# Twitter queries ideas

Tags: sql, twitter

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I was wondering if you have a huge database of tweets, what kind of informative queries would you run on that database?

I just want to have more ideas so I can illustrate that in my study.

Comment: Informative for who?

Comment: For you or anyone just useful answers

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are storing. If it is just the tweets themselves you could run reports on keywords being used, hash tags used within the tweet, etc. If you are storing other information about the user then you open it up to the world of #marketing

Comment: Yea the whole schema of the tweet, user language locations everything